# What could be going wrong in this particular code? I am trying to count the cells whose values are <=7

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub last_column()
    Dim Cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lcol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        MsgBox ("Last column is " & lcol)

        For i = 4 To 7
            'below line is raising an error
            Cell(i, lcol).Value = Application.Countif(Range(.Cells("i", 3), .Cells("i", "lcol")), "<= 7")
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Edit:**

I have changed the code as follows, but although there is no error now there is no output on the cells as well.

```
Private Sub last_column()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim i As Double

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lcol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        MsgBox ("Last column is " & lcol)

        For i = 4 To 7
            .Cells(i, lcol).Value = Application.Countif(.Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, lcol)), "<= 7")
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cell(i, lcol).Value = ...` -> `.Cells(i, lcol).Value = ...`. If that doesn't help please *show* the actual error you're getting.

Comment: `.Cells("i", "lcol")` should be `.Cells(i, lcol)` and two of your ranges aren't qualified to `Sheet1`.  It should be `.Cells(i,lcol).Value =` and `.Range(.Cells(i,3)...`

Comment: `Cell(i, lcol).Value` is not necessarily incorrect, but if you did mean it you need to define `Cell` first. And can I suggest a different name?

Comment: The error is still there. I changed it to .Cells(i, lcol).Value. Error "Type Mismatch" is showing. Any help?

Comment: @SJR just spotted that one - one of the reason not to use `Cell` as a variable name.  Looks too much like `Cells`.

Comment: I have also changed Range to .Range.
The error still shows Type Mismatch.

Comment: what do you get in your lastcolumn message box  ? Include screenshot of your data.

Comment: Please do not post code in comments, as it quickly becomes unreadable. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: It is showing the first column in that row that has a blank cell. Meaning that that's where my excel data ends in that row. So, for me it is showing 49. Which is absolutely right. However, I want to print the count of cells that have values less than or equal to 7 in the 49th column, for each row respectively. It is not printing that. No error is showing, but at the same time, no answer is showing either.

Comment: Your code is changing the *last* column in a row, *not* the first column. For debugging purposes please add a line `MsgBox Application.Countif(.Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, lcol)), "<= 7")` to your code. What does it show?

Comment: What your second piece of code is doing:  `lCol` is the column number of the last cell in row 1 that contains data - presumably column 49.  The loop then counts the numbers that are <=7 in the range `C3:AW3` and placing the result in `AW3`, then it does the same for rows 4, 5, 6 and 7.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, you're right. I found that just a while ago too! Thanks all of you, for all the help. 

Instead of .Cells(i, lcol).Value, it should be .Cells(i, lcol+1).Value. It was indeed printing all my results in the last column, instead of the column next to it. Thanks again!

Comment: My final (CORRECT) code is this:
Dim Cell As Range
Dim i As Double

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    lcol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    For i = 4 To 7
    .Cells(i, lcol + 1).Value = Application.Countif(.Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, lcol)), "<= 7")
    Next i
End With

End Sub

Thanks everyone!